# MFC SDI Error on save on windows 8

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc

I have developed an MFC SDI app, which uses the default `CDocument` `Save`, `Save As` and `Load` Menu Options. When I run this app on Windows XP, Vista, or 7 the app works fine - it can save and load documents without issue. When I run the same app on Windows 8 or 8.1 and click the Save option, the app crashes with a generic error message. Is there something extra that I need to install for it to work on Windows 8? Or is there something special I need to do to get an MFC SDI app to work on Windows 8?

I have tried to install Visual Studio on the Windows 8 machine to compile it there but I only have the Express version, which doesn't come with the MFC libraries, so it will not compile. The PC I wrote the app on, was a Windows 7 pc.

I am not too sure what other information might be useful.

EDIT:

The error message

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Debug it. If you have full Visual Studio to write MFC program, just install it on Windows 8. Another option is remote debugging.

Comment: *"crashes with a generic error message"* - even so, it may be useful to tell us what it says.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio did you use ? Installing a full version of Visual Studio on Windows 8 might be useful. Otherwise you could remote debug the program from your Windows 7 computer (see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38184).

Comment: @RogerRowland I have attached error. I don't have a licence to install Visual Studio professional on the Windows 8 machine, so I guess I am left with remote debugging - thanks for the help.

Comment: You may also install Debugging Tools for Windows on Win8, it is free. Copy source and .pdb files to Win8, and you can debug the program.

Comment: I eventually managed to debug and I was had a null pointer issue: in OnCtlColor I used the `GetFocus()` and didn't check if the `CWnd *` was null or not before using it, which I quickly resolved. Oddly enough, it didn't give me an issue in any earlier version of Windows. Thanks everyone for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to compile MFC applications in older versions of Visual Studio Express, see:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30439/How-to-compile-MFC-code-in-Visual-C-Express

To get this to work in a recent VS Express will probably require some tinkering.